# Change the sort order for posts to include custom field

Tags: custom-field, sort

I want to change the sort order for all my posts.  First by a custom field 'event_begin' which has a value like this:, and then by the regular post date.

The regular posts do not have the custom field populated.

I've tried changing the 'order by' in the wp_includes/post.php file from:

```
function get_posts( $args = null ) {
    $defaults = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'include' => array(),
    'exclude' => array(),
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' =>'',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'suppress_filters' => true
    );
....
}
```

to:

```
function get_posts( $args = null ) {
$defaults = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value' => 'ASC',
        'date' => 'DESC'),
    'include' => array(),
    'exclude' => array(),
    'meta_key' => 'event_begin',
//      'meta_value' =>'',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'suppress_filters' => true
    );
....
}
```

But it's not working.  That actually changes all my menus?!?!?!!?

Additionally I don't like changing the core, can this be done in my child theme?

I need help with this, thanks!

Leslie

Comment: Why you're editing the core for this? you can use orderby parameter directly in your get_posts() function https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters where are you trying to use this function? maybe a bit more info will help

Comment: You should never edit WP core files for a site you intend to publish.

Comment: I am trying to change the orderby parameter in the get_post() function.  (see original message) but it's not working. I don't know where to go from here.  I'm looking for the right code and where to put it.  Thanks